# Django dynamic data in modal window, content changes based on one of select form

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I need a guidance on what and how to use in my situation. I have a modal that adds a new object. For simplification lets assume model only has 2 fields that are based on another models.

```
class Object1(models.Model):
    object2_fk = models.ForeignKey(Object2)
    object3_fk = models.ForeignKey(object3)

class Object2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Object3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

On my website (using only bootstrap + js/jquery if needed) I have a button "add new Object1" which opens modal with 2 Select forms:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="col-sm px-5">
    <select class="form-select">
        <option selected>...</option>
        {% for object in object2 %}
            <option>{{object}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm px-5">
    <select class="form-select">
        <option selected>...</option>
        {% for object in object3 %}
            <option>{{object}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

And in this form it works perfectly but not the way I want. I want to select an object from first select form and want the selected value to be a filter for a second select.
For example:
In first select I choose `APPLE`
Then I want to choose in the second select from `APPLE 1` `APPLE 2` `APPLE 3` `APPLE 4` `APPLE 5`, etc. (always like this, `APPLE` lands in front). Any idea on how to achieve it? Of course if user selects something in second form, it should show blank space.

Comment: Hi, is there anything common between two dropdowns ? you can add data attribute to second dropdown which will match with first drop-down value so depending on this show required values .

Comment: I finally used jquery and AJAX get request to completely separate view- it is sending value from first select to view, view does filter values based on it and returns json dictionary, Then i simply append the <option></option> with every value in loop. It made sense because of I wanted to change some css at the same time anyway.